# Why isn't this file being written to under certain conditions?

Tags: c++, file-io

So I was looking at different questions and answers on this site and one of them mentioned a way of testing if a program has been run more than once. I decided to try it out but I ran into a bug.

This was supposed to be a simple test program to do two different things depending on whether the (initially empty) text file `check.txt` began with an `x` or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file("check.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    if(!file){
        cerr << "no file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char ch;
    file >> ch;
    if(ch == 'x'){
        cout << "result one" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "result two" << endl;
        file << 'x';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Step through it in a debugger to find out what's going on.

Comment: If the file exists but is empty, what will "file >> ch;" achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems in your code:

```
file.fail()
```

That's the condition you should be checking not !file. Secondly, there is no char input for file gets using the << operator please read all the available function overloads for the << operator at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/.